# SoapUI Assertion to match field value within 0.05 on either side

Tags: xml, soapui, assertions

I currently have a Assertion Script that matches a value from the response to a set value. see below:

```
// get the xml response                                             
def response = messageExchange.getResponseContent()                                                 
// parse it                                             
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)                                              
// find your node by name                                               
def node = xml.'**'.find { it.name() == 'total-premium' }                                               
// assert                                               
assert node.toString().matches("(0|27.11|0)\\d*"), 'Expected Result: 0 or 27.11 or 0 Actual Result: ' + node
```

What I would like it to do is to match between values that are 0.05 below and above. So for this particular script, I need the assertion to be true if the `total-premium` value is anywhere from 27.06 and 27.16.

At the moment the Assertion code match the numerical value that is in the field `total-premium` to three values in `matches("(0|27.11|0)\\d*")`.

However, instead of me entering the 11 values `total-premium` could be I want the line  `assert node.toString().matches("(0|27.11|0)\\d*"), 'Expected Result: 0 or 27.11 or 0 Actual Result: ' + node` to pass even if the value in the field `total-premium` is 0.05 plus or minus the value that I manually enter into this script. which for this example is `27.11`.

For a brief overview, I have ~1000 test cases and I use Excel to create the code and assertions for each test case which I then import into SoapUI. So I have the script match automatically depending on what value the Excel Algorithm inputs.

Comment: Can you show what is the input and what is happening with your assertion? At the moment it isn't quite clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [JUnit](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/index.html?org/junit/Assert.html) `public static void assertEquals(double expected, double actual, double delta)`.

```
import org.junit.Assert
// ... your code goes here ...
// new assert
if(node.toDouble() != 0.0)
    Assert.assertEquals(27.11, node.toDouble(), 0.05)
```

Comment: Added you code and got this error `No signature of method: static java.lang.Double.parseDouble() is applicable for argument types: (groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild) values: [35.7] Possible solutions: parseDouble(java.lang.String)`

Comment: @Ross looks like you can use just `.toDouble()` - see my correction.

Comment: Thank you very much